# React Hook Form Validate Image in Edit Form if only image is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, yup, react-hook-form

**Validate Images In Edit Form**

Package I am using:-

- React
- React-hook-form
- yup

My Code is Working fine. but it needs to upload new image every time when I edit my Form.
The Following Form component is used for both add and edit operation of event model.

**What I want to achieve**

I want to edit my event title and venue but not my image.
So I Don't have update my image.

But When I update Image I want there validation rules to be applied

Or only validate the changed fields Of form

**How To Called**

```
//Add Form
<EventForms />

//Edit Form
<EventForms edit />
```

**EventForm.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
// import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import ReactQuill from "react-quill";
import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
// reactstrap components
import {
  FormGroup,
  Form,
  FormText,
  Input,
  Row,
  Col,
  Container,
  Card,
  CardBody,
  CardHeader,
  CardTitle,
  ListGroup,
  ListGroupItem,
  Label,
  Button,
} from "reactstrap";
// import { Editor } from "@tinymce/tinymce-react";

import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { useHistory, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { sendForm, viewId, editId } from "../actions/events";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
const FILE_SIZE = "5000000";
const SUPPORTED_FORMATS = ["application/pdf", "image/jpeg", "image/png"];

function EventForms(props) {
  const schema = yup.object().shape({
    title: yup.string().min(2).max(100).required(),
    venue: yup.string().min(2).max(100).required(),
    // description: yup.string().max(700).required(),
    date: yup
      .string()
      .test("date", "Date is not valid", (value) =>
        dayjs(value, "MM/DD/YYYY").isValid()
      )
      .test(
        "Min date",
        "Date Should be After Today",
        (value) => dayjs(value, "MM/DD/YYYY") > dayjs()
      )
      .required(),
    time: yup.string().required(),
    description: yup.string().nullable().required().min(10).max(1000),
    image: yup
      .mixed()
      .nullable()
      .notRequired()
      .test("FILE_SIZE", "Image Is A Required Field", (value) => {
        // console.log(value)

        return !value || value.length > 0;
      })
      .test("FILE_SIZE", "Image file is too big.", (value) => {
        // console.log(value)
        return (
          !value || (value && value.length > 0 && value[0].size <= FILE_SIZE)
        );
      })
      .test(
        "FILE_FORMAT",
        "Image file has unsupported format.",
        (value) =>
          !value ||
          (value &&
            value.length > 0 &&
            SUPPORTED_FORMATS.includes(value[0].type))
      ),
    // status: yup.boolean().required(),
  });

  const { register, handleSubmit, control, errors, setValue } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    mode: "onChange",
  });
  const history = useHistory();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const details = useSelector((state) => state.details);

  let { id: reqId } = useParams();
  console.log(details.description);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(reqId);
    if (props.edit) {
      dispatch(viewId("event", reqId));
    }
  }, []);

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    data.date = dayjs(data.date, "MM/DD/YYYY").toISOString();
    data.time = dayjs(
      "1970-00-00 " + data.time,
      "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm"
    ).toISOString();

    console.log(data);

    const formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("image", data.image[0]);
    formdata.append("date", data.date);
    formdata.append("time", data.time);
    formdata.append("title", data.title);
    formdata.append("description", data.description);
    formdata.append("venue", data.venue);

    console.log(formdata);
    console.log(formdata.title);
    if (props.edit) {
      dispatch(
        editId("event", reqId, formdata, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        })
      );
    } else
      dispatch(
        sendForm("event", formdata, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        })
      );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Container className="mt--7" fluid>
        <Row className="my-5 ">
          <Col md={12}>
            <Card className="col-lg-10 mx-auto">
              <CardBody>
                <CardTitle tag="h2" className="text-center">
                  Add Event
                </CardTitle>
                <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label htmlFor="title">Title: </Label>
                    <Input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Enter Event Title"
                      bsSize="sm"
                      autoComplete="off"
                      name="title"
                      id="title"
                      invalid={errors.title !== undefined}
                      innerRef={register()}
                      defaultValue={props.edit ? details.title : null}
                    />
                    {errors.title && (
                      <FormText className="text-capitalize pl-1" color="danger">
                        {errors.title?.message}
                      </FormText>
                    )}
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label htmlFor="title">Venue:</Label>
                    <Input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Enter Event Venue"
                      bsSize="sm"
                      autoComplete="off"
                      name="venue"
                      id="venue"
                      innerRef={register()}
                      invalid={errors.venue !== undefined}
                      defaultValue={props.edit ? details.venue : null}
                    ></Input>
                    {errors.venue && (
                      <FormText className="text-capitalize pl-1" color="danger">
                        {errors.venue?.message}
                      </FormText>
                    )}
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label htmlFor="title">Date:</Label>
                    <Input
                      type="date"
                      placeholder="Enter Date"
                      bsSize="sm"
                      autoComplete="off"
                      name="date"
                      id="date"
                      innerRef={register()}
                      invalid={errors.date !== undefined}
                      defaultValue={
                        props.edit
                          ? dayjs(details.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
                          : null
                      }
                    ></Input>
                    {errors.date && (
                      <FormText className="text-capitalize pl-1" color="danger">
                        {errors.date?.message}
                      </FormText>
                    )}
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label htmlFor="title">Time:</Label>
                    <Input
                      type="time"
                      placeholder="Enter Time"
                      bsSize="sm"
                      autoComplete="off"
                      name="time"
                      id="time"
                      invalid={errors.time !== undefined}
                      innerRef={register()}
                      defaultValue={
                        props.edit ? dayjs(details.time).format("hh:mm") : null
                      }
                    ></Input>
                    {errors.time && (
                      <FormText className="text-capitalize pl-1" color="danger">
                        {errors.time?.message}
                      </FormText>
                    )}
                  </FormGroup>

                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label htmlFor="title">Description: </Label>

                    <Controller
                      name="description"
                      control={control}
                      defaultValue={props.edit ? details.description : null}
                      render={(props) => (
                        <ReactQuill
                          value={props.value || details.description || null}
                          onChange={(e) => props.onChange(e)}
                          theme="snow"
                          initialValue="dkasjkj"
                          modules={{
                            toolbar: [
                              ["bold", "italic"],
                              ["link", "blockquote", "code"],
                              [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
                            ],
                          }}
                        />
                      )}
                    />
                    {errors.description && (
                      <FormText className="text-capitalize pl-1" color="danger">
                        {errors.description?.message}
                      </FormText>
                    )}
                  </FormGroup>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label htmlFor="title">Image:</Label>
                    <Input
                      type="file"
                      autoComplete="off"
                      name="image"
                      id="image"
                      innerRef={register()}
                    ></Input>
                    {errors.image && (
                      <FormText className="text-capitalize pl-1" color="danger">
                        {errors.image?.message}
                      </FormText>
                    )}
                  </FormGroup>

                  <div>
                    <Button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-round">
                      Submit
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                </Form>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
  </Container>
    </>
  );
}

// EventForms.propTypes = {

// }

export default EventForms;
```